# 18.04 libhdf5-100 gets installed, I dont know why

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

Whet I do:

```
apt-get install -y libpng-dev libsigc++-2.0-dev libxml++2.6-2v5 libgslcblas0 openssh-client gettext-base rsync slurm-client
```

41 newly installed packages, among them libhdf5-100. Why is that? I dont see this package on dependency lists of any of packages I install by the command pasted above.

Comment: Why did you use `-y` if you didn't expect the results?   Why didn't you specify `--no-install-recommends` if that's what you're after... but really you shouldn't be using `-y` if you're not fully aware of the consequences of the command; a careless newbie mistake.

Comment: A simple query on your *bionic* terminal would have provided that answer... why didn't you perform the `rdepends` query yourself ?

Comment: @guiverc, Thanks! It turned out that HDF is required by Slurm, which is very surprising for me.

Answer (score 1):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/slurm-client

shows it as a requirement.

Why did you use `-y` if you didn't expect the results?

Comment: Thanks! I was so sure that it has nothing to do with Slurm that I omitted checking this one.